# Does Entity Framework 5 (4.4) support Foreign Key to Partial Primary Key mappings?

Tags: entity-framework-5, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I'm not sure I used the correct terminology in the title, but here's what I need to do...

I have a table UserJobs that has a composite primary key on columns EMPNO, and EMPJOBNO.
I have another table UserJobAccounts that has a composite primary key on EMPNO, EMPJOBNO, and JOBACCOUNTNO

Will I be able to properly map one UserJob to multiple UserJobAccounts with this schema?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. A sketch of the model and mapping with data annotations would look like this:

```cs
public class UserJob
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int EmpJobNo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserJobAccount> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class UserJobAccount
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Job"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int EmpNo { get; set; }
    [Key, ForeignKey("Job"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public int EmpJobNo { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 3)]
    public int JobAccountNo { get; set; }

    public UserJob Job { get; set; }
}
```

Or without the data annotations and Fluent API instead:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<UserJob>()
    .HasKey(uj => new { uj.EmpNo, uj.EmpJobNo });

modelBuilder.Entity<UserJobAccount>()
    .HasKey(uja => new { uja.EmpNo, uja.EmpJobNo, uja.JobAccountNo });

modelBuilder.Entity<UserJobAccount>()
    .HasRequired(uja => uja.Job)
    .WithMany(uj => uj.Accounts)
    .HasForeignKey(uja => new { uja.EmpNo, uja.EmpJobNo });
```

Comment: Hey! how did you know I was using Code First?!  haha.. thanks, I'll give it a try Monday. I didn't want to code up my entire model only to find out that this may not work anyway...

Comment: @Juventus18: Because you said "I have a *table*..." which ruled out model-first. And with database-first you had quickly noticed yourself if it works or not by just calling "update model from database" once. Remains code-first :)